# DHCP and Reservations in windows server 2k3

Tags: dhcp

I have a problem with Configuring DHCP Reservations:

in the client, ipconfig: 
Address Leases is: 192.168.188.20

> http:/i160.photobucket.com/albums/t171/dungttvn/123.png

then in the client computer: ipconfig /release

but when i config the Reservations with the fix IP address is: 192.168.188.100 in the sever computer (throught vmnet1) and in the client computer: ipconfig /renew ... it's not work: the address lease is still 192.168.188.20 always!

> http:/i160.photobucket.com/albums/t171/dungttvn/456.png

Someone help me!

Many Thanks!

Comment: Is your client set up for dhcp? I know it sounds dumb, but no harm in checking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bridged or NAT networking in your guest? If your DHCP server is on a separate machine/network to the guest you'll need to use bridged networking.

Comment: the exercise required Host-only!

Comment: Host only should also work for that. You don't have to have bridged if your client and server are on the same vmnet